# Does a quadratic upper bound of subgradients imply unique subgradient (differentiability)?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let $f:\mathcal X\to\mathbb R$ be a convex function with subgradient $\partial f(x)$ at some point $x$ in the domain. Suppose that for all $g\in\partial f(x)$ and $y\in\mathcal X$, there exists $L>0$ such that
$$
f(y) \leq f(x) + \langle g, y-x\rangle + \frac{L}{2}\|y-x\|^2
$$
then is it possible to show that there is only one subgradient at $x$? Namely, $f$ is differentiable at $x$?

Geometrically, what I am trying to figure out is whether you can have a sharp corner which can also be upper bounded by a quadratic.

This is in the context of Nesterov smoothing where it is claimed that you cannot assume boundedness of the subgradients. Still, the proof for convergence of the simple subgradient method depends explicitly on bounded subgradients. Is it that relying on the decreasing step-size to get convergence gives a slower rate and that by removing this dependency, we can achieve a faster rate (i.e. by using Nesterov smoothing)?

Comment: Actually, this $L$ is equal to the Lipschitz modulus of $\nabla f$, if $\nabla f$ is Lipschitz. It would be interesting to see, whether one can prove Lipschitz continuity of $\nabla f$ from this estimate.

Comment: If I understand correctly, given this definition of Lipschitz smoothness, you are asking to provide the Lipschitz continuity of the gradient. Given what you've already done, this no longer has anything to do with subgradients.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x\in int \ dom f$ and $g\in \partial f(x)$. Then for all $y$ in $dom \ f$,
$$
f(y) \le f(x) +\langle g, y-x\rangle + \frac L2 \|y-x\|^2
$$
and
$$
f(x) +\langle g, y-x\rangle \le f(y).
$$
Hence
$$
\langle g, y-x\rangle \le f(y)-f(x) \le \langle g, y-x\rangle + \frac L2 \|y-x\|^2.
$$
Set $y=x+td$ with $\|d\|=1$ and $t>0$ small enough. Then dividing the above inequality by $t$ gives
$$
\langle g, d\rangle \le \frac{ f(x+td)-f(x) }t \le \langle g, d\rangle + \frac L2 t.
$$
Passing to the limit $t\searrow0$ proves $f'(x;d) = \langle g,d\rangle$ for all $d$. Hence $f'(x)=g$ and $f$ is differentiable at $x$.

Comment: Each line seems to be an if and only if. Thus, we can also conclude that if there are two subgradients at a point, then there is no $L$ that satisfies the upper bound in the first equation.